# How to migrate from ASP.NET Web Forms to ASP.NET Web Pages? i.e /default.aspx to /default

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, url-routing

I have designed a website using ASP.NET web form. It contains webpage like

`default.aspx`

`about.aspx`

`contact.aspx`

Now I am migrating WebForms to WebPages (CSHTML). So now, my web pages look like this

`/`

`/about`

`/contact`

So My question is, how to redirect the user who visits `/contact.aspx` to `/contact` page and so on. Is it possible or not?

Comment: Why MVC tag? Are you trying to convert WebForms project to MVC project?

Comment: Maybe redirect to a complete web adresse which is not relative?

Comment: @ThufirHawat, MVC with Razor. I have not created project as MVC or WebPages.. Started from scratch.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier, yes.

Comment: So which is it `Now I am migrating WebForms to WebPages` or `I have not created project as MVC or WebPages.. Started from scratch`...? Is this a question about migrating to MVC, or about setting up your routes? If the latter are you trying to setup routes for Web Forms or MVC?

Comment: @NightOwl888, I mean, when we create a new website vs will ask for website type i.e Webforms, WebPages, MVC, WebPages with Razor etc.. I have chosen none.  My project folder structure will have models and views separately. I use WebPage with Razor syntax (CSHTML).

Comment: @Aravin - If you have never set up a web project before, I recommend using one of the templates and one of the many online tutorials to get started. The MVC project template will automatically provide extensionless URLs for you and give you complete control over the markup. However, there is a lot of extra configuration work to do to set up MVC from scratch if you start with a blank project.

Comment: @NightOwl888, Thanks for your guide. As you mentioned I will go through few online tutorials. & sorry if my question does not meet your level..

Comment: @Aravin There is no bad programmer, only bad question, i don't see any of these here.

Comment: @Aravin If you just want to show **default** in your URL instead of **default.aspx** when someone one visits your page then you can use **URL Rewriting** instead on converting **aspx** pages to **cshtml**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have designed a website using ASP.NET web form. Now I am migrating
>   WebForms to WebPages (CSHTML).
>
> how to redirect the user who visits /contact.aspx to /contact page

It is the responsibility of Route Engine, and you need to specify how you want to route in Application_Start. Web Form and MVC are not backward compatible.

My only advice is if this is a new project, you want to start as new MVC project. Then convert what you have done in Web Form into Controller, View and Model.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [`RewriteModule`](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

Then add smth like this to your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="page.aspx">
          <match url="^default\.aspx$" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="page.aspx">
          <match url="^(\w+)\.aspx$" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: I will check and let u know.